# Making connections to SV generated interfaces

Tags: system-verilog

I need to make connections to ports of a SystemVerilog interface that have been generated.  But I don't know what the instance names of the generated interfaces are, so I can't work out how to connect to them.

e.g., if I generate the code like this:

```
generate
  for (genvar abc_if_inst = 0; abc_if_inst < NUM_ABC; abc_if_inst++)
    abc_if   if_abc   (.clk(clk), .resetn(resetn));
endgenerate
```

How do I reference the interface signals, e.g. I'm assuming it's something like this:

```
.port_x (if_abc_GEN_INST_NUM.port_x),
.port_y (if_abc_GEN_INST_NUM.port_y),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is best to put a `begin`-`end` around the content of the for-loop and apply a label. If you not use a label then a automatic label will be added as `genblk` suffixed with unique id number. Section 27.6 of [IEEE Std 1800-2012](https://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/1800-2012.html) goes into detail explain the generate block naming works. Section 27 is all about generate blocks. One example about generate for-loops on page 753.

For your provided code, try:

```
generate
  for (genvar abc_if_inst=0; abc_if_inst<NUM_ABC; abc_if_inst++) begin : mygen
    abc_if   if_abc   (.clk(clk), .resetn(resetn));
  end
endgenerate
```

Then you can connect by as:

```
.port_x (mygen[0].if_abc.port_x),
.port_y (mygen[0].if_abc.port_y),
// ...
.port_x (mygen[NUM_ABC-1].if_abc.port_x),
.port_y (mygen[NUM_ABC-1].if_abc.port_y),
```

Note that the index of `mygen` needs to be a constant, such as a parameter, another genvar, or hard coded value.

Comment: Great answer, thanks.  But shouldn't it mention the interface instance name?  Perhaps something like:

    .port_x (mygen[0].if_abc.port_x),